# Showing two Lie subalgebras are conjugate

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have two Lie subalgebras of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R}$) denoted $\mathfrak{g}_1$ and $\mathfrak{g}_2$ which are spanned by $\{h_i,e_i\}$ for $i=1,2$. For $i=2$ they are given explicitly by the standard choices
$$h_2=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}\quad e_2=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
However, both pairs satisfy the commutation relations $[h_i,e_i]=2e_i$. I know that all Lie subalgebras dimension $2$ of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ are isomorphic, but I want to show something stronger, namely that we have $c_S(\mathfrak{g}_1)=\mathfrak{g_2}$, where $c_S$ denotes conjugation by $S$. To prove this, I attempted the following.

Let $\phi:\mathfrak{g}_1\to\mathfrak{g}_2$ be an isomorphism. Then let $\phi(h_1)=ah_2+be_2$ and $\phi(e_1)=ch_2+de_2$. Using the fact that the isomorphism must preserve the bracket, this forces $a=1$ and $c=0$. So $\phi(e_1)=de_2$ for some real number $d$. If we let $S=\text{diag}(\sqrt{b},1/\sqrt{b})$ then $c_S(e_2)=\phi(e_1)$. It remains to be shown that $b=0$, so that $c_S(h_2)=h_2=\phi(h_1)$. But I have no idea whether this is even true, and if it is, how to prove this. I would appreciate some advice.

Comment: "I know that all Lie subalgebras of $sl(2, \mathbb R)$ are isomorphic". Certainly not ... Maybe you mean all two-dimensional subalgebras. Regardless, unless I misunderstand your question, it is trivial that your subalgebras given by basis elements with certain brackets, are isomorphic, namely by mapping $e_1$ to $e_2$ and $h_1$ to $h_2$. To show that they are conjugate, you will presumably need to express $e_1, h_1$ in a *full* basis of $sl_2$.

Comment: Yes, of course I meant of dimension 2, my mistake. I did consider that obvious isomorphism but I thought it would somehow make me "lose" information by choosing something explicitly. Are you suggesting I extend the isomorphism of subalgebras to an automorphism of $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$? Or merely that I try to express the isomorphism is the standard basis.

Comment: Let me put it this way: Nowhere in your approach do you use that $\mathfrak g_1$ is contained in $sl_2$. For all we know, we could have $h_1 = \pmatrix{0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&-2\\}, e_1=\pmatrix{0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&17\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\}$, and the algebra $\mathfrak g_1$ spanned by these is certainly not conjugate to $\mathfrak g_2$. As said, I think you must *express $h_1,e_1$ in a a basis of $sl_2$* (which you could not do for the above). A convenient choice of such basis would contain $e_2, h_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I believe to have found a solution.